# Update/replacement for properties maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a fairly old maven project that uses the plugin below to write a properties file (to my understanding). I am currently updating the project dependencies and found out that the providers services have been terminated.

Is there a more up to date way of doing this, an example pom.xml extract would be great!!!

Thanks,

Adam

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>tests</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/appversion.properties</outputFile>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *the providers services have been terminated.*? Is the plugin using some external website that doesn't run anymore?

Comment: I assume you mean the shutdown of codehaus? The new home is https://github.com/mojohaus which is not fully ready yet (http://www.mojohaus.org) Furthermore why not using default filtering capabilities?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, In regards to why I am not using default filtering...I guess that is part of my question, how would I go about achieving above using this?